# Find a formula for $0 · 1 · 2 + 1 · 2 · 3 + 2 · 3 · 4 + \dots +n(n + 1)(n + 2)$, for $n \in \mathbb N$

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n i(i + 1)(i + 2)$$

$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n i^3 + 3i^2 + 2i$$

$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n i^3 + 3\sum\limits_{i=1}^ni^2 + 2\sum\limits_{i=1}^ni$$

$$= (\frac14)n^4 + (\frac12)n^3 + (\frac14)n^2 + n^3 + 3(\frac{n^2}2) + (\frac{n}2) + n^2 + n$$

$$ =n^4 + 3n^3 + 8n^2 + 3n$$

Why does what I did above not work?

Comment: How did you get from the second to last step to the last step...?

Comment: I just combined the like terms and took their sum.

Comment: No, I mean, how did you add up the terms in the second last line and get what you got for the last line? I compute from what you have written: $1/4n^{4} + 3/2n^{3} + 11/4n^{2} + 3/2n$. I haven't verified whether your second to last line is correct though.

Comment: Note that $${n+3 \choose 4} = {n+2 \choose 3} + {n+2 \choose  4} = \frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{6} + {n+2 \choose  4}.$$  Now continue to reduce the last term.

Comment: There is only one $n^4$ term, which is $\frac {1}{4}n^4$. How then, did you get $n^4$? What happened to $\frac 14$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Required formulas:
$$\sum_{i=1}^n i^3=\left(\frac{n(n+1)}2\right)^2$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^n i^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^n i=\frac{n(n+1)}2$$

---

I will start off at the third step.
$$\sum_{i=1}^n i^3+3\sum_{i=1}^n i^2+2\sum_{i=1}^n i$$
$$=\left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^2+3\cdot \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}+2\cdot \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$
$$=\frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}+\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{2}+n(n+1)$$
$$=\frac{n^2(n^2+2n+1)}{4}+\frac{2n(2n^2+3n+1)}{4}+\frac{4n^2+4n}{4}$$
$$=\frac{n^4+2n^3+n^2+4n^3+6n^2+2n+4n^2+4n}{4}$$
$$=\frac{n^4+6n^3+11n^2+6n}{4}$$
$$\color{green}{\sum_{i=1}^n i(i+1)(i+2)=\frac{n^4+6n^3+11n^2+6n}{4}}$$

Comment: I just checked your answer and it doesn't look like it works. For example if $n = 1$, the formula gives $24/6$. Can you comment what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @NewOrleans I found my mistake. It should work now. I had made a calculation error when saying that $(n+1)(2n+1)=2n^2+\color{red}4n+1$, it should be $2n^2+\color{green}3n+1$.

Answer (score 9):

It is very much easier to note that $$n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)-(n-1)n(n+1)(n+2)=4n(n+1)(n+2)$$ from which you get a telescoping series.

This is related to the binomial identity $\binom nr+\binom n{r+1}=\binom {n+1}{r+1}$ with $r=3$, and the pattern clearly generalises.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to these excellent answers, there is a general approach that words for *all* partial sums of the form:
$$S(n) = \sum_{k=1}^n f(k),$$
where $f$ is a degree $d$ polynomial.

We must have that $S(n) = g(n)$, where $g$ is a degree $d+1$ polynomial, with $d+2$ coefficients to determine.  Then we evaluate $S(n)$, for $n=1,\dots,d+2$, to get a linear system with $d+2$ equations and unknowns that can be solved for.

More strikingly, if you have a proposed solution to such a problem, a *proof* of its correctness requires merely that you check its correctness for $d+2$ different values of $n$!

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{\sum_{k = 1}^{n}k\pars{k + 1}\pars{k + 2}:\ {\large ?}}$

> \begin{align}&\color{#c00000}{%
> \sum_{k = 1}^{n}k\pars{k + 1}\pars{k + 2}}
> =\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{\pars{k + 2}! \over \pars{k - 1}!}
> =3!\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{k + 2 \choose 3}
> =6\sum_{k = 1}^{n}\oint_{\verts{z}=1}{\pars{1 + z}^{k + 2} \over z^{4}}
> \,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> \\[3mm]&=6\oint_{\verts{z}=1}{1 \over z^{4}}\sum_{k = 1}^{n}\pars{1 + z}^{k + 2} 
> \,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> =6\oint_{\verts{z}=1}{1 \over z^{4}}\,
> {\pars{1 + z}^{3}\bracks{\pars{1 + z}^{n} - 1} \over \pars{1 + z} - 1} 
> \,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> \\[3mm]&=6\ \underbrace{\oint_{\verts{z}=1}{\pars{1 + z}^{n + 3} \over z^{5}}
> \,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}}_{\ds{=\ {n + 3 \choose 4}}}\ -6\
> \underbrace{\oint_{\verts{z}=1}{\pars{1 + z}^{3} \over z^{5}}
> \,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}}_{\ds{=\ 0}}\ =\ 6{n + 3 \choose 4}
> \\[3mm]&=6\,{\pars{n + 3}\pars{n + 2}\pars{n + 1}n \over 4\cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot 1}
> \end{align}

$$\color{#00f}{\large%
\sum_{k = 1}^{n}k\pars{k + 1}\pars{k + 2}
={1 \over 4}\,\pars{n + 3}\pars{n + 2}\pars{n + 1}n}
$$

Comment: This is what I call "nuking the mosquito"

Answer (score 1):

$$
0 \cdot 1 \cdot 2 + 1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 + 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4 + \cdots +n(n + 1)(n + 2)
=
3!\ \sum_{k=1}^{n+2} \binom{k}{3}
=
6 \binom{n+3}{4} 
$$

The key sum is the sum of a column of Pascal's triangle, which is found by induction using Pascal's rule.

Comment: Yout last equality is obtained by counting the $4$-element subsets of $\{1,2,3,\dots,n+3\}$ in two different ways.